# Passing in String to jQuery function as Object

Tags: jquery, json, string, object, arguments

This might be a stupid question, but I'm trying to pass in a string of settings I've constructed in the following format:

```
"setting1" : "value", "setting2" : "value", "setting3" : "value"
```

The above is saved to a string named args. Nothing special, but I'm wanting to pass it in as an argument to a function.

```
$('#element').functionName({ args });
```

I'm not sure what I'm missed here....
Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is `args`?  What are you getting stuck on?

Comment: sorry, args is the var name for the string above... I'll edit

Comment: Back up a bit to where the string comes from. Makes more sense to modify it's source to create object or JSON, not a string formatted as shown

Answer (score 3):

If you really have a string such as this:

```
'"setting1" : "value", "setting2" : "value", "setting3" : "value"'
```

You can parse it using `JSON.parse` and get an object out of it like so:

```
var args = JSON.parse( "{" + str + "}" );
$('#element').functionName(o);
```

But in reality you probably want to just create such an object instead of a string from the start, e.g.:

```
var args = {"setting1" : "value", "setting2" : "value", "setting3" : "value"};
$('#element').functionName(args);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a stupid question. Try:

```
var args = JSON.parse("{'setting1' : 'value', ...}");
```

And then pass the "args" variable into your function.